# Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: storesListsSelected is not defined vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuex, vuex4

```
<script>
  import {
    mapGetters,
    mapActions
  } from "vuex";
  export default {
    name: 'Stores',
  data() {
    return {
        selected: storesListsSelected
    }
  },
    methods: {
      ...mapActions(["fetchStores"]),
      onChange(event) {
        console.log(event.value.value);
        // localStorage.setItem('shop-id',event.value); 
        }
    },
    computed: mapGetters(["storesList","storesLists","storesListsSelected"]),
    created() {
           this.fetchStores()
    }
  }
</script>
```

here mapGetters to call data return values ( return { selected: storesListsSelected})
i am trying.but i got error Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: storesListsSelected is not defined.
how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

you have forgotten use 'this'

```
data() {
  return {
    selected: this.storesListsSelected
}},
```

you can change name of property like this and dont need define data property

```
...mapGetters("storesList","storesLists", { selected: "storesListsSelected" })
```

Comment: values not show this.storesListsSelected